# Loading a UINavigationController from a nib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following code:

```
UINavigationController localNavigationController = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

And here's the CustomView.xib

[image]

am I wiring it wrong? I am getting the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIWindow setParentViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b74fe0'
```

Comment: Remove window from the objects category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading the NIB, and asking for the object at index 0, wouldn't that be the UIWindow?  Where are you using the navigation controller?  IF you are using it in your main application, why don't you just create an iVar and a property for it as an IBOutlet and hook it up? It will automatically get loaded for you...